# Read and write NtGlobalFlags with C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read and write NtGlobalFlags with C++ with the following code:

```
#include <intrin.h>
#include <winternl.h>

PPEB pPeb = (PPEB)__readfsdword(0x30);
DWORD dwNtGlobalFlag = *(PDWORD)((PBYTE)pPeb + 0x68);
```

But [__readfsdword is still undefined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/readfsbyte-readfsdword-readfsqword-readfsword?view=vs-2019). What header should I include?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. The offset to NtGlobalFlag is different among OS:

```
#include <winnt.h>
#include <winternl.h>

PPEB pPEB  = (PPEB)__readgsqword(0x60);
DWORD flag = *(PDWORD)((PBYTE)pPEB + 0xBC);
DbgPrintA("NtGlobalFlag = 0x%X", flag);
```